# Derivative of the inverse of $y=(a+bx)e^{cx}$

Tags: derivatives, inverse, exponential-function

I need to solve for the 1st derivative of the inverse of $y=(a+bx)e^{cx}$ but my calculus is a bit rusty. I know that to get the inverse function, I would have to use the Lambert W method but I think that the 1st derivative is different.
Anyway, if I understand correctly, the 1st derivative of the inverse is just 1/y'(yinv).
In this case that would make my answer:
$$\frac 1{be^{cy}+ce^{cy}(a+by)}$$
If someone could verify this for me or point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I haven't checked that your derivative is correct but yes, $\left(f^{\circ -1}\right)'=\cfrac{1}{f'}$ and that's how you should compute it.

Comment: I can't figure out what you mean by "1/y'(yinv)."

Comment: Sorry I meant to write that as one over the 1st derivative of y evaluated at the value of y inverse.

Comment: If I could have one clarification, am I right in using y in the answer or should it be x?

Comment: The calculation is correct. There is no pleasant way, however, to express the derivative in terms of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

If $y = f(x)$,
then
$dy = f'(x) dx$.
If you are lucky,
$f'$ is easier to invert than $f$.

Let's see.

$y=(a+bx)e^{cx}$,
so
$dy = (a+bx)c e^{cx} + b e^{cx}
= e^{cx}( ac+bcx + b)
= e^{cx}( ac+b+bcx)
$
and this is of the  same form,
so you will have to use
the good old W-function
to invert $y'$.

Too bad.

Comment: I've been looking at the W-function for the past day and I can't figure out how to apply it in this case. Could I please have some assistance in doing so?